# pgadmin unable to connect to server fe_sendauth no password supplied

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I have pgAdmin4 on Mac and I am trying to register a server using a pem file.
However it is giving me an error saying no password supplied. There is no password to be supplied frankly, so I am confused.

[image]

Comment: The password bring requested is the one on the 'connection' tab. If you think one shouldn't be needed, check the pg_hba file.